# Reactjs how to position images?

Tags: reactjs, image

I am using reactjs to create a simple applet displaying some images on a webpage.
My kind question is what is the best approach to manually position "flask" and "flask2" images at the bottom of the page like in this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02PN7.png)
My output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVXCX.png)

this is my App.js

```
import pipe from './img/pipette.png';
import './App.css';
import { useSpring , animated } from 'react-spring';
import { useDrag } from 'react-use-gesture';
import obj1 from './img/flask1.png'
import obj2 from './img/flask2.png'
import gradient from './img/gradient.jpg'



const stil = {
  color: "orange",
  backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
  padding: "7px",
  fontFamily: "Arial"
};

function App() {
  const logoPos = useSpring({x: 0, y: 0});
  const bindLogoPos = useDrag ((params)=>{
     logoPos.x.set(params.offset[0]);
      logoPos.y.set(params.offset[1]);
    
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <div>
        <p style={stil}>scara de culoare a turnesolului</p>
      </div>
     
        <animated.div {...bindLogoPos()} style={{
         
             y: logoPos.y,
             x: logoPos.x,
        }}>

              <img src={pipe} className="App-logo" alt= "pipe" />
        </animated.div> 

        <div className="gradient-container">
        <img src={gradient} width="175" className = "gradient" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <img src={obj1} width="175" className = "flask" alt=""/>
        <img src={obj2} width="175" className = "flask2" alt=""/>

       
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: don't you like to use css grid?

Comment: @MWO

 EDIT*  setted a ClassName for the div containing the image
       '<div Classname="flask1-container">
        <img src={obj1} alt=""/>
        </div>' 

but while implementing   '.flask1-container {
  top: 50 px;
  left: 35 px'

in the css style sheet, no changes can be seen.

Comment: div Classname="flask1-container" should be div className="flask1-container"